# request.user not working properly and can't be assigned to hidden model field

Tags: django, request

I am making a little image sharing website which is a lot like a blog. When I try to assign form.author = request.user, it doesn't work and the form on my website returns 'this field is required' error.

I tried even other similiar projects on github to check if the error is in the project but it seems not because I get errors there too. But the interesting part is when I try to print the request.user object it prints the object without a problem but when I try to assign it for some reason it returns null.
Then I tried twisting the code in every possible scenario but I couldn't debug it.

This is my models.py

```
class Meme(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meme = models.ImageField(upload_to='memes/')
```

This is my view

```
def upload(request):
    form = MemeUploadForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.author = request.user
            obj.save()
            redirect('blog-index')
    return render(request, 'blog/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my form

```
class MemeUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meme
        fields = ['title', 'meme']
```

When I try to get the view to return the request.user it gives me Attribue error: User' object has no attribute 'get' but when I try to print the request.user object it gives prints my object perfectly like there aren't any errors.

Comment: I don't understand why you get a `This field is required` message for `author` - it isn't included in `fields`. In your question you mention setting `form.author`, but you should set `obj.author` instead. The actual code in your question looks ok. Double check that the code in the question actually gives the `Attribute error: User' object has no attribute 'get'` message, and if it does, add the full traceback. If you have missed out any code (e.g. an `__init__` method for the form) then add that to the question.

Comment: yes by form.author I mean obj.author obj=form.save(commit=False)

Comment: As an aside, you should use the `login_required` decorator with the view otherwise you'll get errors when you save the form for anonymous users.

Comment: Yes im still early in the dev process, I'll add it later if I manage to fix this bug haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it was actually the imagefield that causes problems, because I didn't make the form 'file upload form' and the problem is not in request.user object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MemeUploadForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.author = request.user
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog-index')
return render(request, 'blog/upload.html', {'form': form})
```